# Are there any modules where you can import H2Database data into drupal 7 as nodes?

Tags: migrations, importing-exporting

I'm working with the java h2 database engine and there is data that i want to query/import everyday. Is there a module or how would I go about importing such data into drupal 7 as nodes?

Comment: Have you tried **anything**? You know, you can import anything if you can have it in CSV or XML, right?

Comment: no im just curious if there was anything out there already as i searched on google and couldnt find anything relating to h2 and drupal. thought someone else might have dealt with something similar. maybe there is a sandboxed module that I dont know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is likely to use the Migrate module and a custom php H2 database driver.

This is not easy.

You can follow this to get php working with PDO and Java H2. http://www.webdevelopersdiary.com/1/post/2012/07/jamp-an-ultra-portable-php-web-server-and-database-stack-in-java.html

From there you will need to write a class for the migrate module that [extends the migrate source class](https://www.drupal.org/node/1152164)